# make phone vibrate when the called party answer the call

Tags: android

```
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
    Log.i("CALL_STATE changed " ,"phoneState");

    switch (state) {
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
        Log.i("IDLE","CALL_STATE_IDLE");

        break;

    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
        //This is where we know call is established

        Vibrator mVibrator = (Vibrator) mcontext.getSystemService(mcontext.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        // Vibrate for 250 milliseconds
        mVibrator.vibrate(250);
         break;


    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
        Log.i("RINGING","CALL_STATE_RINGING");
        break;

    default:
        Log.d("TAG", "Unknown phone state=" + state);
    }
}
```

In the OFFHOOK state, ie when the called party answer the call, the phone is not vibrating. what could be the possible reasons??

Answer (score 1):

The reason could be, that you did not add the Permission to the AndroidManifest.
Add the following to your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Regards

Comment: Its not because of permission ,i have given the permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE

Comment: Try adding a longer intervall. Do you test it on a device? If so what device? Add a logger to it and see if you reach the case

Comment: ya, i have tried it on a device(huawei) and even tried with longer interval.

Comment: And your device can vibrate i guess? I had a problem with a Nexus 7 that actually cant vibrat and i wondered the whole time..

Comment: Than i have no clue... the `mcontext` is your context right? Did you check if the instance of Vibrator isnt null? so it's really created? Did you enable the vibrate at your device?

Comment: The present context is mcontext.And how to check instance of Vibrator is null or not ??